# Feature Importance in GAM models with Linear and S-term Features

Tags: generalized-additive-model, importance

I've fitted a GAM model with a set of variables some fitted just as-is while others have been given an s-term due to earlier analysis indicating more complex / non-linear relationships to the target variable.

The GAM model is used for predicting performances on the target variable and with that I am in the processes of defining intervals that can be roughly thought of as, if a person is within the intervals on most features used in the model, it can be assumed that that person is likely to have a higher value on the target variable. As GAM's dont require us to initally transform any variables the defined intervals works quite well and Im validating them as we speak.

However, the issue Im facing is that the given intervals should of course be reflected in the importance of a feature (its contribution to the model). If a variable has a high abs coefficient we can assume that smaller changes in the feature will result in larger moves within the target variable. To determine how the interval should be adjusted I've assigned ranks to each feature based on their absolute coefficient, but I cannot do this for the s-term features as they come with multiple coefficients and are not directly comparable to the coefficients of a non s-term feature.

Im therefore looking for advice on how to rank features & / or calculate feature importance for the given set of features.

The model was fitted as:

```
response_variable ~ A.Flexibility + C.Diligence + H.Sincerity + O.Inquisitivness + 
    O.Creativity + O.Aesthetic_Appreciation + EF_Tower_attempts + 
    s(A.Gentleness) + s(days_worked)
```

The given coefficients are:

```
Intercept)  3562.110698
A.Flexibility   47.947561
C.Diligence -102.804352
H.Sincerity -133.116834
O.Inquisitivness    -102.421886
O.Creativity    -47.976478
O.Aesthetic_Appreciation    76.974283
EF_Tower_attempts   -127.041283
s(A.Gentleness).1   -8.225032
s(A.Gentleness).2   9.639281
s(A.Gentleness).3   12.161738
s(A.Gentleness).4   17.768379
s(A.Gentleness).5   -6.621655
s(A.Gentleness).6   19.172601
s(A.Gentleness).7   -9.349299
s(A.Gentleness).8   101.631939
s(A.Gentleness).9   34.818561
s(days_worked).1    88.436757
s(days_worked).2    -133.497057
s(days_worked).3    -62.004499
s(days_worked).4    102.764766
s(days_worked).5    5.541388
s(days_worked).6    102.365175
s(days_worked).7    25.042981
s(days_worked).8    -471.710410
s(days_worked).9    68.639665
```

As for the s-term I am also going to include edf, chi.sq & p.values

```
s(days_worked)
chi.sq = 7.60
p.value = 0.0602
edf = 2.28

(A.Gentleness)
chi.sq = 0562
p.value = 0.6669 
edf = 1.50
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or guidance, really anything would be highly appreciated!